# How to convert coordinates in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, coordinates

I have a JSON file with coordinates where (0.0) is at top left corner (*first picture*). In Unity (0.0) is at the center of the screen (*second picture*). I am looking for a way where I can convert my file's coordinates to Unity coordinates.

[image]

So my question is how can I convert the coordinates from the first picture to Unity Coordinates?

For example at position (2.3) I have letter 'A'. How to convert it to match with Unity?

I have already tried `Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint` but I always get the same result for all of the inputs.

This is what I get:
[image]

Comment: Do you know the width and height of the grid you're working with?

Comment: Yes I am getting the width and height of the board.

Comment: Is your camera in position (0,0)?

Comment: Yes camera at (0,0). From the first pair of images, if you see (2,3) from the left grid that has the Letter A, and also see (2,3) on the right grid it will be on top right and that is the reason I have this problem.

Comment: Can you post your current process of transforming the coordinates, expected results for a single letter and actual results for that letter?

Answer (score 0):

try this python code, or translate it to your language:

```
def transformXY(x,y, jsonSizeX,jsonSizeY):
  x -= jsonSizeX/2
  y -= jsonSizeY/2
  return x,y

x,y = getDataFromJson(...)
x,y = transformXY(x,y, jsonMaxX, jsonMaxY)
useInUnity(x,y)
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not clear. Please explain or rewrite your code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
int unityX = -gridWidth/2 + jsonX/gridWidth * gridWidth;
int unityY = gridHeight/2 - jsonY/gridHeight * gridHeight;
```

Edit:

I just realised you would probably need the position of the center of the tile in your grid. In that case the code above needs some modifications:

```
float unityX = -gridWidth/2 + jsonX/gridWidth * gridWidth + 0.5f;
float unityY = gridHeight/2 - jsonY/gridHeight * gridHeight - 0.5f;
```

This will place the objects you're working with in the center of their respective tiles.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work. Not sure if it's something wrong with the gridWidth and gridHeight I am using.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work" what exactly do you mean?

Comment: I am getting different coordinates and letters are placed on wrong position. I added a screenshot of what I am getting until now.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way I can think of would be to have an empty `GameObject` where you want `0,0` to be and then calculate the positions relative to that `GameObject`

```cs
public class CoordinateAdjustment : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject positionAdjustmentGameObject;
    public float cellSize = 1f; // Set to 1f for this example can change to your needs

    public Vector2 GetPosition(int row, int column)
    {
        Vector2 position = new Vector2
        (
            positionAdjustmentGameObject.transform.position.x + (column * cellSize),
            positionAdjustmentGameObject.transform.position.y + (row * cellSize)
        );
        return position;
    }
}
```

Might need some refining but will work.